# Gradle fails to find the dependency

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have used this tool to publish my library to sonatype https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push. I can see that it's uploaded and signed correctly.
 but when I try to add the dependency to another project gradle can't find it 
 
here is what i get: Error:Failed to find: com.github.mohd-bh:app:1.0.0 

 though I already included mavenCentral() in repositories block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this link http://search.maven.org/ to search the maven repository.

When I searched for your library, I could not find it.

Sonatype requires that you push your library from the staging server to the release server by using their website tool.  You may not have done that which would result in the library not being published to maven.

Comment: When I try to release the library, the button is disabled on the website

Comment: Select the library in the top panel and check in the bottom panel of the screen for errors. For example, the signing key may not be able to be verified against a key site. By drilling down through the library details you should be able to see either a confirmation message or an error message.

Comment: can't find any error, here is what i see: Activity 
Last operation completed successfully. Also in "violations" column it says "No CLM data is recorded"

Comment: I figured out the issue..  I have to close the repo first then promote and finally release..